# How do I solve for a key error when trying to combine two data frames?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine two data frames and it keeps throwing a key error (KeyError: 'series_id') and I cannot figure out for the life of me what's going on. I've tried changing the type of join and using dataframename.merge.

```
from detect_delimiter import detect
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests as r
import sys

def df_creator(file):
    res = r.get(file)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        #delim will attempt to auto detect the delimiter and default to ','
        #if one isn't found.
        delim = detect(res.text, default=',')
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.text), delimiter=delim, engine='python')
        print("Data Frame has been created for %s"%file)
        return df
    else:
        print("There was a problem. Please check the URL or Filename.")
        sys.exit()


def data_join_check(df1_count, df2_count):
    if df1_count == df2_count:
        print("%s cases have been merged."%df1_count)
    else:
        differnce = df1_count - df2_count
        print("The data has a discrepency of %s cases")%differnce



employment_information = df_creator('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.series')
employment_information = employment_information[employment_information['end_year'] == 2020]


ei_county = df_creator('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.64.County')
ei_county = ei_county[ei_county['year'] == 2020]

series_merge = pd.merge(employment_information, ei_county, how='inner', on="series_id")
```

Comment: The source of the error is likely a typo or the column name got changed or dropped somewhere in your code. The error is telling you that there is something wrong with this column's spelling or something else: `KeyError: 'series_id'`

Comment: `'series_id'` does not exist in one of your dataframes, at least jjsut prior to running the last step. Is it an index column in one of the dataframes? If so, then that would be another reason. You would have to merge on the the index with something like `left_index=True, right_on='series_id` if for example the column was on the index in the left dataframe but a normal column in the other dattaframe.

Comment: You can also do `ei_county.columns` or `employment_information.columns` to see the column names of the two dataframes prior to joining.

Answer (score 0):

Using David's responses I was able to find there was a significant amount of whitespace causing issues with the header "series_id" and so I had to remove it from the header and the rest of the data.